# Is search broken?

Tags: bug, search

Looks like [query below](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion%20answers%3a0) yields 0 results.

Is search broken? That usually return hundreds of results.

[image]

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356685/search-is-extremely-slow (multiple issues with search atm, including but not limited to: slow results, no results, error message about maintenance)

Comment: possibly related but I just got an error message on the meta *homepage* saying something like "it is not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to unexpected error" - it loads OK now so I don't know the exact text of the error